# UWP vs MFC desktop app developpement

Tags: mfc, uwp

I am c# developer, in other words many projects that i have finished made by C#, fewer projects by Delphi and other by PHP and JAVA, now I must deliver solutions where the performance is crucial, I need to going to others technologies like UWP or MFC, but I think UWP is very limited, there are tonnes of constraints, other part MFC and visual c++ all knows is so hard to learn.
So which is the best(final) orientation to make a desktop business app?

Comment: If you want to use C# and not to use UWP, you can use Windows Forms or rather WPF..

Answer (score 0):

There can only be subjective answers to this question. As a general rule you can get better performance by being "closer to the metal" so C++ is probably a better choice. Especially if you are impacted by some of the limitations of UWP.

That said, it's not all about the language you use. You can write slow programs in C++ and fast programs in C#/XAML.

UWP also encompasses distribution technologies and so you can distribute your C++ built app as an APPX by using the [Desktop bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the performance critical part is:

- Low memory and disk footprint? (below 400 KByte)
- Can execute on cash-register running Win95?
- Fast startup?
- Fast 3D rendering?
- Fast business logic calculations?
- Great development tool support, that supports fast new development?
- Works great on all versions of Windows or cross platform?

I'm guessing it is the business logic part, so I would probably implement the GUI in your favorite .NET GUI rendering tool. Then put any performance critical business logic in a standard C++ DLL you can interface from the .NET code.